# Is there a way to display an image in the body of an email using an image URL

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm working on a personal web crawler project where I want it to be able to send emails as notifications with an image inside the body of an email. I see plenty of documentation on how to download and then display an image using smtplib. However, I do not see any examples of displaying an image without downloading it.

I was wondering if it's possible to display an image inside the body of an smtplib email using only the image URL without needing to download the image. (You can use an image URL to put an image in an email body using gmail, so I was assuming it might be possible via automated python script.)

Comment: If it's HTML email, just use a normal `<img src="URL">` tag.